# How to show and save only one value on Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I have a model in which I created all the data types of Odoo, char, float, many2many…. etc, I show this model in a view where, depending on the type of data selected by the user, “only one” of these types of data will be shown to enter a value. I am showing the type of data selected by this domain in the `view -> attrs = "{'invisible': [('fields_type', '! =', 'Char')]}"`

In addition, when “only one” of the fields is saved in the database, the other values in the line are in `<null>`.

My questions are:

1. Will there be any “dynamic” way to show only the selected field, without having to load all fields in the view and hide them with attrs?
2. What would be an "optimal" way to store these values in a database? Do all fields in a single model or should I separate the different fields using some kind of inheritance?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Manuel Alejandro Bouza Lavoy,

Yes, you can do it in a dynamic way with **fields_view_get** method. Where you can check your condition and based on that you can add on your view.
2nd thing you can use with one model to store the value in the database.no need the separate models.

Thanks